# Convert HTML(without rendering HTML page) to PDF with angular 7

Tags: html, css, typescript, angular7

Am looking for solutions for generate PDF file(s) from HTML. HTML source generated dynamically like when user click on check box or button, in that case HTML added on element.

I tried with `jsPDF` and `Html2Canvas` package but problem is it will not work without rendering HTML page. Below is example for `jsPDF`

```
let doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.addHTML(document.getElementById("obrz"), function() {
       doc.save("obrz.pdf");
    });
```

Thanks in an advance.

Comment: About a year ago I looked into this and there really weren't any good front end solutions. I'd try finding a backend solution like [EO.pdf](https://www.essentialobjects.com/Products/EOPdf/Default.aspx) if that's an option for you.

Comment: @FunkeyFlo i need for front end side.. reason we have 1000 of reports which is generated pdf... i think it will impact on performance